# BlazorSeverSide.How it comes that the BackTop component didin't work?

Tags: antd, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to use a simple ant design component in my BlazorSeverApp,while it doesn't work.Can anyone tell me the reason? Thanks a lot.
Here's my Razor Page.

```
<div class="mat-layout-grid">
        <MatButton Raised="true" OnClick="UpdateABSTI">Submit</MatButton>
        <MatButton Raised="true" OnClick="ExpendAll">Expend All</MatButton>
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ABSTI.CreatorDisplayName))
        {
            <p>Last Update by @ABSTI.CreatorDisplayName at @ABSTI.CreateDateTime</p>
        }
    </div>
    <KeyInfoTitle TitleText="@TitleText" OnSetProjectDone="@SetProject" />
    <div id="ABS" class="text-left">
        <table style="border:black solid;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" width="1200" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
            <tr class="text-center" style="background-color: #99CCFF">
                <td width="300">描述 <br> Description </td>
                <td width="500">标准选项  <br> Standard Option</td>
                <td width="400">备注  <br> Comments</td>
            </tr>
            <ABS_HU ABSTI_HU="@ABSTI.HU" IsExpended="@IsExpendAll" />
            <ABS_WSS ABSTI_WSS="@ABSTI.WSS" IsExpended="@IsExpendAll" />
            <ABS_SYSTEM ABSTI_System="@ABSTI.System" IsExpended="@IsExpendAll" />
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="300" class="text-center">
                </td>
                <td width="500" class="text-center">
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="400">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <BackTop></BackTop>
    </div>
```

It's the Usage in official documents.

```
<div>
    <div>
        Scroll down to see the bottom <strong> gray</strong> button
    </div>
    <BackTop></BackTop>

</div>
```

Comment: How is it not working? Please explain if there are any errors or symptoms.

Comment: There's no any error.The problem is that the Backtop component can't display.

Comment: And i also tried it in another project,it works.It's confusing.